# $G_1\cup G_2\setminus F_1\cup F_2\subset (G_1\setminus F_1)\cup (G_2\setminus F_2)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to show that $(G_1\cup G_2\setminus F_1\cup F_2)\subset (G_1\setminus F_1)\cup (G_2\setminus F_2)$

where $G_1,G_2$ is open and $F_1,F_2$ is closed

Hints would be welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the condition "$G_1,G_2$ is open and $F_1,F_2$ is closed". The relation you need is true for any sets $G_1,G_2,F_1$ and $F_2$.

To prove see:

- $G_1\setminus (F_1\cup F_2)=[(G_1\setminus F_1) \cap (G_1\setminus  F_2)]\subset (G_1\setminus F_1)$
- $G_2\setminus (F_1\cup F_2)\subset (G_2\setminus F_2)$
- $\begin{align}(G_1\cup G_2)\setminus (F_1\cup F_2)&=[G_1\setminus (F_1\cup F_2)]\cup [G_2\setminus (F_1\cup F_2)]\end{align}$

Comment: @Rose:Got it or not??

Comment: Yes, I get it now. Thank you!